# React jsx setting element attributes

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the an elements attributes that is from a state

```
    this.state = {
        label : 'Hello',
        columns: [4, 8],
        test: 'has-success'
    }
```

I was trying to set the col-md value like so:

```
<label className="control-label text-sm-right col-sm-{this.state.columns[0]}">
```

but that didnt work.  So I wanted to see what that values is if I used the console.log()

```
console.log('control-label text-sm-right col-sm-{this.state.columns[0]}');
```

and the output shows that it didnt change the value to col-sm-4:

[image]

but when I use it this way it works:

```
<span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.columns[0]}</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a string to the variable. Something like this instead

`className={"control-label text-sm-right col-sm-"+this.state.columns[0]}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6, you can use template string literals.

```
<label className={`control-label text-sm-right col-sm-${this.state.columns[0]}`}>
```